# SSRS - Exporting a huge report into PDF

Tags: reporting-services

I have an extensive report which renders to 5000+ pages in SSRS. I want this report to be exported to PDF, saved and sent to users. I report throws "System Out of memory exception" error trying to export into PDF.
I tried using subscription services, but that fails with "Failure sending mail: An error occurred during rendering of the report.Mail will not be resent." error.
Any ideas on how to get this report exported to PDF? Is there a way I can break report into multiple PDFs after 100 pages or so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you referenced the values in this post?
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/fbca93f7-18db-4581-af2f-afd4fe9b54de/ssrs-report-export-to-pdf?forum=sqlreportingservices

Comment: Thank you for your reference. It was truly helpful. I was able to export the report now after I added the parameter